# Suppose that $f$ is a real valued function such that its second derivative is discontinuous.Can you give some example?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

In an interview somebody asked me the following question but I failed to give the answer.
Suppose that $f$ is a real valued function such that its second derivative is discontinuous. Can you give some example?

Comment: Under the supposition of the question, an example would be $f$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers so far give differentiable functions that fail to have a second derivative at some point. If you want to second derivative to exist everywhere and be discontinous somewhere, you can use the following function:

$$f(x) = \int_0^x t^2 \sin(\frac1t)\ dt
$$

Its first derivative is $x \mapsto x^2 \sin(\frac1x)$, which is differentiable everywhere, and while its derivative (and hence the second derivative of $f$) is defined everywhere, it is discontinuous at $0$. Therefore, $f$, $f'$ and $f''$ are defined everywhere, and $f''$ is discontinuous at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Start backwards: Take some function that is discontinuous, say a typical step function:
$$
f''(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \le 0 \\ 2 & x > 0 \end{cases}
$$
Integrate twice.

Comment: Of course, the $f'(x)$ you get this way isn't differentiable at $x=0$, just at every point $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x) = x^{3/2}$ has $f^\prime(x) = (3/2) x^{1/2}$ and $f^{\prime\prime}(x) = \frac{(3/4)}{x^{1/2}}$ which is discontinuous.

Comment: Where is it discontinuous? It is continuous at every point where it is defined.

Comment: Not the second derivative.

Comment: Again, where is it discontinuous? It isn't defined at $x=0$, and is continuous at every $x>0$.