# Does the existence of the derivative at a point imply the existence of the left and right derivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I'm asking this because I've seen "results" in the internet that state:

A function $f$ is differentiable at $x = a$ if and only if both the right-hand derivative and left-hand derivative at $x = a$ exist and both of these derivatives are equal.

And the counter implication appears in passing in my notes:

If a function $f$ is differentiable at $x = a$ then both the right-hand derivative and left-hand derivative at $x = a$ exist and both of these derivatives are equal.

However, the function $x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ even thought the lateral derivatives don't exist at $0$. This example appears in my notes, which is distressing because (unless I'm committing a logical fallacy) then it's not true that the existence of the derivative at a point imply the existence of the left and right derivative at that point (which would not be consistent with the previous statement).

Comment: How did you get that the "lateral derivatives" (as you put it) don't exist at $0$ for $x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$?

Comment: The function you describe is not even defined at zero, it certainly is not differentiable there.

Comment: Your second sentence is a true theorem. What maybe confuses you is that the function $x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}$ (defined to be $0$ at $x = 0$) is differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but the derivative is not continuous at $x = 0$. The left and right hand limits of the derivative do not exist, but this is not the same as the left-hand and right-hand derivative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated by @levap in the comments, you are likely confusing the (right-hand side, RHS) derivative at $0$ with the (RHS) limit of the derivative. I will just add details to clarify. Assuming you mean $f(0)=0$.

The derivative at $0$ is by definition
$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}h = \lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{h^2\sin(\frac1h)-0}h = 
\lim\limits_{h\to0}h\sin(\frac1h)=0$.

Similarly the RHS derivative at $0$ is 
$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}h = \lim\limits_{h\to0^+}\frac{h^2\sin(\frac1h)-0}h = 
\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}h\sin(\frac1h)=0$,

and the LHS derivative at $0$ is
$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}h = \lim\limits_{h\to0^-}\frac{h^2\sin(\frac1h)-0}h = 
\lim\limits_{h\to0^-}h\sin(\frac1h)=0$.

On the other hand when $x\not=0$ we could use differentiation formulas (apart from the limit definition of the derivative, which we could also use but it would be unnecessary), to obtain that

$f'(x)=2x\sin(\frac1x)-\cos(\frac1x)$, $x\not=0$.

Now, it is true that the limits $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f'(x)$, as well as $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f'(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}f'(x)$ do not exist, that is the derivative $f'(x)$ has no limit (no RHS limit, no LHS limit) as $x\to0$, but this is a different matter than the derivative (the RHS derivative, the LHS derivative) of $f$ at $0$. The latter, as we saw earlier, exists and equals to $0$.

To illustrate, I enclose a couple of graphs (different zoom). $f(x)$ is shown in black, squeezed in between grey $x^2$ an $-x^2$. It should be clear from the picture that the tangent line at $0$ exists and has slope $0$. On the other hand in every neighborhoos of $0$ the slope of $f$ varies between $\approx\pm1$. That is, the dirivative $f'(x)$, shown in red, varies between $\approx\pm1$ (when $x$ is close to $0$ but different from $0$), and hence the limit of the derivative does not exist, as $x\to0$.

[image: x^2 sin 1/x]

Zoom in

[image: x^2 sin 1/x zoom in]

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming that the RHS derivative with the RHS limit of the derivative. Which is true **if** the RHS limit of the derivative exists, right?

Comment: I didn't think the latter would be right and searched MSE with terms: first derivative discontinuous at a point  . Got several results including one answer essentially taking the antiderivative of the function you consider and obtaining a function everywhere ... well need to think but will leave this for later, this particular link is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352449/suppose-that-f-is-a-real-valued-function-such-that-its-second-derivative-is-di/352462#352462

Comment: As far as I know, for a function to be differentiable at a point, left and right hand limits of the derivative must exist. And I think you showed that in the first equations. Did I understand it right? Checking the derivative's lateral limits at a point is not the best way to determine the existance of derivative at that point. And to be more precise, we should use the first equations you showed as a definition.

Comment: @LarsSmith For a function to be differentiable at a point, the left and right hand side limits of the derivative need not exist. If fact the derivative need not exist, except at that single point. There are nowhere differentiable (bounded) functions, let $g$ be such a function, and let $f(x)=x^2g(x)$. Then $f'(0)=0$ but $f'(x)$ does not exist if $x\not=0$.

Comment: I am very glad that you replied that soon, thank you. The definition of the derivative is $\frac{{f\left( {x + h} \right) - f\left( x \right)}}{h}$. So I see that it is about the limit of the point on the function, not on its derivative. I saw a very trivial question just then and I can solve it but I just couldn't really comprehend the basics of it. The question is actually asking "if a function is differentiable at a given point $(x=1)$, are its derivative's two sided limits equal at that point?". https://prnt.sc/wb0sfv Could you please not solve but explain this to me?

Comment: @LarsSmith you will make me learn more languages. First, it is $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ (i.e, not just the fraction but its limit). Re that problem, in order for $f$ to have derivative at $1$ you need $3x^2=b$ when $x=1$ so $b=3$. You also need $f$ to be continuous at $1$, so $1^3+a=b1$, so $1+a=3$. Hope you could find $a$ and $a+b$ from here. (From what I see in the link you provided, your translation is incorrect. The correct one is "If $f$ has derivative at $1$, find the sum $a+b$." Yes, in that problem, derivatives exists, and left/right limits are same, as long as $b=3$, $a=2$)

Comment: Thank you :) "in order for $f$ to have derivative at $1$ you need $3x^2 = b$ when $x = 1$ so $b = 3$." Doesn't this imply that the derivative's two sided limits must exist and be equal to each other or is this just because it is polynomial or something? That's why I didn't translate it word by word because this is the main question I would like to learn about.

Comment: @LarsSmith It is just because (each side) is a polynomial, hence all derivatives (of each side, of all orders) exist and are continuous. (Each side is defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$ even if you only focus on $(-\infty,1)$ or $[1,\infty)$.) They already exist and are continuous, but now you need to match them at $1$, to make the derivative (for the piece-wise $f$) at $1$ exist (and in particular make $f$ continuous at $1$).

Comment: Thank you so very much, sir.

Comment: @LarsSmith You are welcome, thank you